# How to avoid needing a root class for a JSON object when using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

Given this JSON,

```
{
    "token": {
        "accessToken": "scrciFyGuLAQn6XgKkaBWOxdZA1",
        "issuedAt": "2022-11-06T22:54:27Z",
        "expiresIn": 1799
    }
}
```

I can get the `DeserializeObject` to work if I define the model as this

```
    public class Root
    {
        public Token Token { get; set; }
    }

    public class Token
    {
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        public DateTime IssuedAt { get; set; }
        public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
    }
```

And use this call:

```
Root myRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(apiResponse);
```

The third-party API I am calling has all methods returning a similar JSON response, in that it has a header object containing a single object of a specific type, such as:

```
{
  "user": {
    "preferences": {},
    "address": {},
    "name": {},
    "email": "string",
    "segmentName": "string"
  }
}
```

which requires a model looking like this:

```
    public class Address
    {
    }

    public class Name
    {
    }

    public class Preferences
    {
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public User user { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public Preferences preferences { get; set; }
        public Address address { get; set; }
        public Name name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string segmentName { get; set; }
    }
```

I do not want to be having to define a different `Root` class for every one of the JSON responses. Is there a way to avoid this?

EDIT 14/11.

Another JSON response looks like this:

```
{
  "provider": {
    "TOTAL": {
      "count": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Again, it's an "empty" root object containing the specific object I need.

As **zaitsman** indicated in his comment, by typing the `DeserializeObject` call to use a `<Dictionary, T>`, where `T` is the actual object I'm after (such as `Token` or `User` or `Provider`), it gets around the need for a root object.

EDIT 15/11.

Just one more example;

```
{
    "provider": [
        {
            "accountType": [],
            "loginHelp": "string",
            "baseUrl": "string",
            "loginUrl": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "id": 0,
            "lastModified": "string",
            "status": "Supported"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case, the *C#* code to deserialize looks like this:

```
providers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Provider>>>(apiResponse)["provider"];
```

Using `Dictionary<string,T>` removes the need to define a root class, and `T` has to be defined as a `List<T>` since the content is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can achieve this.

One of them is:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, User>>()["user"]
```

This will give you a `Dictionary<string, User>` so you can use any other type as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that defining `Root` objects is better approach because it makes expected JSON structure defined explicitly but if you want you can use Newtonsoft's LINQ API via `JObject` ([docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm)):

```cs
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var user = jObject["user"].ToObject<User>();
```

Similar can be done via JsonNode API for `System.Text.Json` (available starting .NET 6).

Comment: Or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jObject.ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it by having a wrapper defining all possible "content" names as properties. Then having one property to return the value which is populated after de-serialization.

```
public class Response<T>
{
   public User User { get; set; }
   public Token Token { get; set; }
   public Token AuthToken { get; set; }
   public XYZ XYZ { get; set; }

   public T Content => GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name != nameof(Content)).Select(p => p.GetValue(this)).Single(v => v != null) as T;
}
```

Then, just having a method for deserializing like this

```
public T DeserializeResponse<T>(string json)
{
  return Deserialize<Response<T>>(json).Content;
}
```

There is also a more dynamic way possible, if there are too many different contents you need to retrieve, but that would require overriding some more reflection and going deeper into deserialization process.

Comment: This answer may work for me, depending, as you say, on how many of these JSON responses I need to deserialize. I'll be spending more time on this during the week and will mark this as the answer if it works for my scenario. Thanks.

Comment: @SiBrit that is not a very good answer both from design and performance standpoint.